# Jquery toggle flickering in IE7 when navigating the website

Tags: jquery, navigation, toggle

I created a toggle with jquery but it is flickering every time i navigate the website in IE 7???

```
  jQuery.noConflict(); // start substituting $ for jQuery
jQuery(document).ready(function( ) {
jQuery('#loginToggle').hide();
 jQuery('#login img').toggle(
        function() {

       jQuery('#loginToggle').slideToggle(200);
         jQuery('#info').animate({ left:"-=235px", width: "420px"},"fast");

        },
        function() {
          jQuery('#loginToggle').slideToggle(200);
         jQuery('#info').animate({ left:"+=235px",  width: "420px"},"fast");
      }
    ); // end toggle
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When doing animation with the parameterized list like your doing `{ left:"+=235px ..."}` I found that it helps to put a `position: wpx xpx ypx zpx;` on the element that you're trying to animate.

That way there is actually a css style already on the element that jquery can modify... I think IE did have a problem with that.